# Laravel: Trouble displaying JavaScript inside Blade @if block

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

Is it  possible to do something like this ...

```
@if(Session::has('foo'))
    <script>
    // My JavaScript function
    </script>
@endif
```

I am trying to put Facebook pixel code only if a certain session variable is there.

Please advise.

---

**Please Note [Update]:** The session variable is coming in fine. I can read it. Issue is somewhere else. It's perplexing the heck out of me.

Here is the code:

```
@if(session('displayPixelCode'))
    #1. Session variable's value is : {{ session('displayPixelCode') }}          
    <script>
        // My JavaScript code goes here 
    </script>
@else
    #2. Session variable's value is : {{ session('displayPixelCode') }}
    <script>
        // My JavaScript code goes here 
    </script>
@endif
```

If I look at the bottom of the **rendered view** I see this (correct value of session variable) ...
[image]

If I look at the **rendered page source** I see this (the @else branch gets executed).
[image]

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes... doesn't work. The session variable is coming in fine. I can display a random text there... but apparently the <script> tag is not being displayed.

Comment: did you try adding an alert inside the script tag and see if that gets triggered?

Comment: Yes that works. But what I am trying to do is echo/output/print some JavaScript code within an opening and closing <script> tag. As an example ... let's says I am trying to put Google Analytics code on certain pages based on the logic.

Comment: Have you double checked that the <script> code isn't in the source?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what was causing this. Had to use `!is_null(session('displayPixelCode'))`

Here is what it looks like now:

```
@if(!is_null(session('displayPixelCode')))
    <script>
        !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)  
        {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?  
        n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};  
        if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';  
        n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;  
        t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];  
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',  
        'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');  
        fbq('init', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');  
        fbq('track', 'PageView');  
        fbq('track', 'Lead');  
    </script> 
    <noscript>
        <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&ev=PageView&noscript=1"/>
    </noscript>       
@endif
```

Comment: That sounds weird because `if(null)` will always evaluate to `false` (see [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/uc676)).

Comment: I think it's fine. The IF statement is saying if a certain variable is not null (that is, it exists), then do something. See https://3v4l.org/eXrME

Comment: Well, you are right, the only case where `!is_null($value)` will return `false` is when the value is actually `null`. Opposed to that, a simple `if($value)` will also consider `$value` false when it is `0`, `''`/`""` (empty string) or `false`. When I look at your example, I cannot imagine you want to print the JavaScript code if `session('displayPixelCode')` returns one of the above. To me it would only make sense to output the JS code if this session variable returns `true` or `1` as alternative. So I consider your solution dangerous, to be honest.

Comment: I am also checking for isset. What do you suggest I should do? If($value) does not work. It's perplexing. Please see my update in the question.